# Problem in backgroung of list when scrolled

Tags: android

I have list view to display data,it dispalys well with white color background initially,but when i scrolled the background of list view has been changed to black,when i stop scrolling it get white background,i need to have white color background when i scrolled,how can i fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a attribute on you list view tag. `android:colorCacheHint="#00000000"`

Answer (score 2):

The xml attribute `android:cacheColorHint` for your ListView is what you are looking for. Explained in the documentation: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html